# Requiring a Javascript file in another JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var FS = require('fs');
var Path = require('path');
var Jsonfile = require('jsonfile');

var search = function () {};

search.prototype.projectContainerDirPath = null;

/*
 * interface
 */
search.prototype.setPaths = function () {
  this.projectContainerDirPath =  Path.join(__dirname, '../projects');
};

module.exports.search = search;
```

This is my `a.js` file. In this file, I have created an object called `search` and added a variable and a function to its prototype. Finally i have exported the search object.

I have `b.js` file which `require`, `a.js` file. `b.js` file is shown below

```
var search = require("./search");
search.setPaths();
```

What i'm trying to here is to use all the functions and variables of `a.js` inside `b.js`. But when `b.js` is run, Node JS returns below error

```
TypeError: search.setPaths is not a function
```

I tried exporting a new object of `search`.

```
var obj = new search();
module.exports.search = obj;
```

And again creating a new object of `search` in file `b.js`

```
var search = require("./a");
var obj = new search();
search.setPaths();
```

But those two attempts was failed. The reason why I'm using prototype is, there are some more objects that inherits the prototype of `search` object. So is there any way i can export this `search` object and use it in another JavaScript file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
module.exports = search;
```

And looks like 'search function' is constructor, so you should better use first character as capital to distinguish that this is a Function or Constructor like this:

```
var Search = function() { ... }
var obj = new Search();
```

** UPDATED **

Ok, I read your question again, I found wrong point. In **search.js** file:

```
var search = function() {};
module.exports = search;   // module.exports.search and this syntax is same
```

**search** is a constructor, not an object. In b.js file, you are using search's prototype function **setPaths**, but **search** is a just function object that means it connected **Function.prototype** not **search.prototype**. If you want to using the prototype function directly from different file, you should export instantiated Object, not a constructor:

```
var search = function() {};
module.exports = new search();
```

this is what I did and it works 100%:

```
// server.js
var search = function() {};
search.prototype.setPaths = function() { ... };
module.exports = new search;  // you can skip () if argument is empty
```

and this is b.js:

```
// b.js
var search = require("./search");
search.setPaths();
```

Comment: first code in your question called **a.js** but what actually you are importing is **./search**, which means **./search.js**, not **a.js**. I think that's the problem.

Comment: that's because the actual file name is search.js. i just used a and b as an example. i copied  the actual code and past the code here. i edited the question.

Comment: I just updated answer, and it worked(tested). Hope will help you.